# creating a one unique parameter from two foreign keys

Tags: sql

I created a table that has two foreign keys

```
create table RezultatiTesta 
(
    RezultatiID int identity(1,1) not null primary key,
    Polozio bit not null,
    OsvojeniBodovi decimal not null,
    Napomena text,
    KandidatiID int,
    TestoviID int,

    Foreign key (KandidatiID) references Kandidati(KandidatiID),
    Foreign key (TestoviID) references Testovi(TestoviID)
)
```

I wanted to make it work to give the user the chance to input more combinations like one candidate can do more tests and one test can bee written by more candidates but they can not do the same test twice so if I insert `1 1`, `1 2`, `1 3` it should work but if I repeat `1 1` it should write an error but I can't make it to work like that. I don't know how to make two foreign keys act as a one unique parameter, I hope you understood what I wanted to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just want unique constraint on the two columns:

```
create table RezultatiTesta (
    RezultatiID int identity(1,1) not null primary key,
    Polozio bit not null,
    OsvojeniBodovi decimal not null,
    Napomena text,
    KandidatiID int,
    TestoviID int,
    Foreign key (KandidatiID) references Kandidati(KandidatiID),
    Foreign key (TestoviID) references Testovi(TestoviID),
    Constraint unq_KandidtId_TestoviId unique(KandidatiID, TestoviID)
)
```